# Remote sensor cloud connection

Tags: networking, sensors, arduino, communication, wireless

i'm just starting out in Arduino, IoT etc; I was given the Elgoo Uno R3 Arduino starter kit at the weekend and i've been trying to soak it up.

I would like to make a number of sensors for my van, temperature (inside and out), humidity and others, and connect them to the cloud for analysis.

Let's start with the temperature; I would like a sensor to read the temperature (inside and out) and send it to the cloud and then I would use further analysis tools to graph this etc (probably Shiny, R or Javascript). I would like the sensor to work wherever I am.

I have read quite a lot of articles that involve wi-fi (Node MCU etc.), this is not possible out in the middle of nowhere. I think i would just go down the SD card data logger over wifi conection if i'm honest. I've also read quite a bit about the server side and possibilities of Raspberry Pi etc so that's fine.

But what I really want to know is, how do you connect a sensor so it's firing data off over the network (the mobile network?) to the cloud, not dependent on wi-fi? Is this where something called GSM Shield's come in? And to do this presumably i'd need a SIM card for my country (UK) to enable a connection?

The last issue would be powering said device, i assume this sort of thing requires quite a bit of power but that isn't strictly for this post. Sorry for simplistic qu's, it's all new to me!

Comment: Don't forget to DuckDuckGO for `low cost data sim for iot`

Answer (score 1):

You need an IoT device which has the facility to connect sensors this device will send your sensor data to the Gateway(via LTE modem). You need to run an application on the Gateway that can forward all your data to cloud server of course on the cloud server you need to have some application running. your mobile phone, tablet and all other devices will connect to that cloud server and you can see status of your sensor devices on your mobile app.

Comment: as soon as it's at the cloud i'm in comfortable territory, no problem. So i have to have LTE modem present somewhere and then connect the sensors to that? this strikes me as a little overkill

Comment: if the sensors are at different location then you need one gateway(with LTE modem) + one other connectivity such as bluetooth, loRa, wifi to talk to end points just like Client Server each clients have a list of sensors each of them send their data to Server via bluetooth or LoRa or wifi to the Server and Server sends it to the cloud.

Comment: ok thank you, the different locations would just be situated within one vehicle but i understand. What if it's one single sensor? can i not just use a SIM card for GPRS connection and set the Arduino/RasPi up as a server to send data?